# profinite density in $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, nt.number-theory

To check that a subgroup of $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ for $n>2$ is profinitely dense, one need only check that it surjects under all the projections mod $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ (which, while in appearance infinite, is usually a finite computation). What about $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ is there anything resembling a decision procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This group is virtually free so subgroup separable so a fg subgroup is dense iff it is the whole thing. For non-fg subgroups an algorithm probably doesn't make sense.

Comment: I was afraid you would say that, but that is certainly a decision procedure.

Comment: One can of course check if a f.g. subgroup is the whole thing. 

Comment: Yes, that part I know how to do...

Answer (score 2):

There is an algorithm to check if a subgroup of a free group is dense in the pro-nilpotebnt-topology (not every finitely generated subgroup is pro-nil-closed). It involves finding a rank of a certain matrix modulo arbitrary $p$ which in fact only need a finite number if checks (subgroup is $p$-dense iff the matrix has full rank mod $p$). So it is in some sense similar to considering factor-groups modulo congruence subgroups. See Margolis, S.; Sapir, M.; Weil, P. Closed subgroups in pro-V topologies and the extension problem for inverse automata. Internat. J. Algebra Comput. 11 (2001), no. 4, 405–445.

Comment: A lot of people in automata theory and semigroup theory would be VERY happy if somebody could find an algorithm to check density in the pro-solvable topology on the free group.

Comment: @Benjamin: how come? Is there a reference for the applications?

Comment: @Igor: See the last remark in the paper I mentioned. I think Ben meant his paper also: uinger, K.; Steinberg, B.
On the extension problem for partial permutations.
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 131 (2003), no. 9, 2693–2703. The problem is, in particular, related to a problem of equality of two complexity classes. Not P=NP but similar.  

Comment: H. Straubing and D. Therien, Regular languages defined by
generalized first-order formulas with a bounded number of bound
variables, in: “STACS 2001” (Dresden), Lecture Notes in Comput.
Sci. 2010, Springer, Berlin, 2001, pp. 551–562.

Comment: A number of algorithmic problems about finite monoids and about regular languages are equivalent to pro-solvable density. 

Examples: 

1. Decide if a regular language can be defined in first order logic supplemented with mod-p quantifiers using two-variable sentences (variables may be reused). 3 variables is enough to do anything that can be done with an arbitrary number but 2 is restrictive. 

2. The power set of a finite solvable group is a monoid under usual mult. of subsets. Decide which finite monoids are quotients of submonoids of power sets of finite solvable groups.

Comment: Also see a more CS paper, the $NC^1$ class and its subclasses are defined there: Barrington, David A. Mix; Immerman, Neil; Straubing, Howard On uniformity within NC1. 
J. Comput. System Sci. 41 (1990), no. 3, 274–306.